How to allow user to download an image using a reactjs button click?
EDIT:  What makes this different is that I'm perfectly able to access these resources with the browser using an <img> tag, but can't get the data with a fetch.  The 'similar' questions don't have this issue and/or don't explain why a 'get' with the browser is different than a 'get' with a fetch request.  Further, similar questions don't have client-only solutions.
I have spent a day working on this.
I have a public s3 bucket with images.  These images are accessible if you go to https://my-bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com/path-to-my-image.jpg in your browser.
I have a reactjs application that shows these images using an <img src={imageFilename} /> jsx tag.
I want to add a button that will download the image to their computer for them.
The first method was to add a 'download' attribute to the a href tag, like so:
const ImageDownloader = () => {
  const imageUrl = 'https://my-bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com/path-to-my-image.jpg'; 

  const downloadImage = () => {
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = imageUrl;
    link.setAttribute('download', 'downloaded-image.jpg'); // Specify the desired file name
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <img src={imageUrl} alt="Image to Download" style={{ width: '300px', height: 'auto' }} />
      <br />
      <button onClick={downloadImage}>Download Image</button>
    </div>
  );
};

This just opens a new tab to view the image and does not actually download the image.  I don't know why the 'download' attribute doesn't download, but it appears not to be a viable tool.
Research indicates I might need to download the image with fetch or similar and use a blob.  I would get CORS errors with the fetch (but, notably, I can easily view the images in the reactjs app) so I included 'no-cors' in the below; the browser console suggested this might be a solution.  Turns out, it's probably not.
const ImageDownloader = () => {
   const imageUrl = 'https://my-bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com/path-to-my-image.jpg'; 
    
   try {
        // Fetch the image with no-cors mode
        const response = await fetch(imageUrl, {
          mode: 'no-cors'
        });
      
        const blob = await response.blob();
        
        const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
          
        const link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = url;
        link.setAttribute('download', 'downloaded-image.jpg');
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
        document.body.removeChild(link);
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
        
   } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error downloading the image', error);
          }

This gives me the 'download' in the browser, but the file is of zero bytes.  If I look a the network response in the dev console, I see that the full file size got downloaded.
I tried npm packages file-saver and js-file-download too.
Long story short - I've got an image that I can easily access in my browser and I just want to let people download it.  Please help.

mode: 'no-cors'  are you aware of what this does? If not, why are you using it?

I was not aware.  Now I am.  I used it because the browser suggested it in the details of the cors error and without it, I only got a cors error with no data.

There's a difference between cross-origin embedding and cross-origin reads. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy#cross-origin_network_access. You need to enable CORS for your S3 objects if you want to access them via fetch() (see the 2nd duplicate link)
